# How to get a specific user's data from a database

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a chat application, and in it I have a `RecyclerView` which has `username`, `userstatus`, and `userimage`.

When I click on the `RecyclerView`, it opens a Profile activity and it shows me the `username`, `userstatus`, and `userimage`. I can get this information from the `RecyclerView` using `putExtra()`, but I want to get it directly from the database.

If I call the user from `SharedPrefManager`, it gets only my profile's name but not the others. How can I achieve this? Maybe there is a way of getting the user from the `RecyclerView`?

I used Google to search for a solution to my problem, but I didn't find anything useful.

Here as you can see I'm putting extra information to my intent:

```
class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewName, textViewEmail;
        public Context context;
        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView imageView;
        public UsersViewHolder(final View itemView, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_username);
            textViewEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    int userid = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(mCtx).getUser().getId();

                    if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        User clickedDataItem = userList.get(pos);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + clickedDataItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    String name = textViewName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String email = textViewEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("email", email);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("id",userid);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(profileIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And in the next activity I'm getting it:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
        String email = intent.getExtras().getString("email");
        int userid  = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ProfileName.setText(name);
        ProfileStatus.setText(email);
```

Everything works fine except userid it gives error if I want to show clicked user's userid in toast message. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.

Comment: It would help if you included your code and explained clearly what it is that you're trying to achieve and why your current code fails to provide the desired result. Use the `{ }` button or CTRL + K to format your code correctly.

Comment: passing the `userId` with the `Intent` might be the most common way to do that ...

Comment: @MihaiChelaru I included my code

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes I'm doing the same way you said but it gives error when I want to show userid of clicked user